# GUI for calculating the minimum amount of coins needed

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm new to GUI building and slightly confused at the code below... When I run the program, it definitely runs but when you enter the amount of change, it doesn't calculate how many quarters, dimes, etc. it just puts a "0" in. I looked at my code and there aren't any errors.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MinCoinsGUI extends JFrame
{

    private JTextField changeTF = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField quartersTF = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField dimesTF = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField nickelsTF = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField penniesTF = new JTextField(3);

    public MinCoinsGUI()
    {
        JButton CalcChangeBTN = new JButton("Calculate");
        JButton ClearBTN = new JButton("Clear");

        CalcChangeBTN.addActionListener(new ChangeBTNListener());
        ClearBTN.addActionListener(new ClearBTNListener());

        quartersTF.setEditable(false);
        dimesTF.setEditable(false);
        nickelsTF.setEditable(false);
        penniesTF.setEditable(false);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2, 2, 2));

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter Change (1-99)"));
        mainPanel.add(changeTF);

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Quarters"));
        mainPanel.add(quartersTF);

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Dimes"));
        mainPanel.add(dimesTF);

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Nickels"));
        mainPanel.add(nickelsTF);

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Pennies"));
        mainPanel.add(penniesTF);

        mainPanel.add(CalcChangeBTN);
        mainPanel.add(ClearBTN);

        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        pack();
        setTitle("Minimum Coins");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    class ChangeBTNListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String changeString = changeTF.getText();
            int change = Integer.parseInt(changeString);

            String quartersString = changeTF.getText();
            int quarters = Integer.parseInt(quartersString);

            String dimesString = changeTF.getText();
            int dimes = Integer.parseInt(dimesString);

            String nickelsString = changeTF.getText();
            int nickels = Integer.parseInt(nickelsString);

            String penniesString = changeTF.getText();
            int pennies = Integer.parseInt(penniesString);

            while (change >= 25)
            {
                quarters++;
                change -= 25;
            }

            while (change >= 10)
            {
                dimes++;
                change -= 10;
            }

            while (change >= 5)
            {
                nickels++;
                change -= 5;
            }

            while (change >= 1)
            {
                pennies++;
                change -= 1;
            }

            changeTF.setText("" + change);
        }
    }

    class ClearBTNListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            changeTF.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MinCoinsGUI window = new MinCoinsGUI();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the values in `quartersTF, dimesTF` and so on at all.  All you're doing is calculating the number of quarters, dimes and so on, all the while diminishing `change` until it reaches zero, then setting that zero back into `changeTF`.  If you want to see values in `quartersTF, dimesTF` and so on, you'll need to set them.